# VB.Net I want to disable all textboxes as default in form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am learning to use vb.net to show legacy data I loaded into an Access database. I need to display the data in the textboxes on my form but, under normal circumstances, I don't want the user to be able to modify or even enter the textbox fields by tabbing or a mouse click. In some circumstances I want to turn on those textbox fields so authorized users can update the information. I have been searching for an answer and trying lots of properties both in design and at run time. Any thoughts on how I can do this? I suppose I can make two identical forms, one with labels and one with textboxes and switch as necessary. Any thoughts on the best way to do this?

Comment: Use the enabled or readonly properites

Comment: Thanks! Using the enabled property allows me to display the information but doesn't allow the user to click on any of the text boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Here I assume that every *Textbox* in your form can be edited. Add this to the event in which you check for user authorization.

```
 If IsUserAuthorized = True Then
    For Each myTxtBox As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
         myTxtBox.ReadOnly = False 'or myTxtBox.Enabled = True
    Next
 Else
    For Each myTxtBox As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
        myTxtBox.ReadOnly = True 'or myTxtBox.Enabled = False
    Next
 End If
```

Comment: Thanks Aethlen. The enabled property did the trick. When I used ReadOnly users could still click into the text box.

Comment: Kindly mark this as answered if it helped you. Thanks and good luck to you! :)